# Unable to delete a strange looking file name

Tags: windows-10, file-management

There seems to be a strange looking file on a system I have - Running Windows 10.

The file name is called .jpg. and I cant seem to find a way to delete it.
Tried through both explorer and the command prompt (logged in as administrator) - See screenshot link below.

Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I presume you also can't rename it through Explorer?

Comment: @EngineerToast - Unfortunately no it wont let me through explorer either  :-(

Comment: what about doing an `attrib` in that directory to see if there are any attributes set. Another idea is an unvisible char attached to the name, Typing `del /Q /A "[Tab]` might get you further.

Comment: you can try using the short name: try `dir /X` and check for a short name in the column immediately to the left of the normal name. Then try renaming or deleting the file using the short name.

Comment: That D-drive, Is it a local drive or a network drive? If it's a NAS (with a driveletter assigned) you can't delete that file (I had the same problem last week with a directory with a space after it). You would need to delete it via a console session on the device itself (or maybe the web-interface). If it is a local drive you could try del \\?\D:\public_html\images\T\.jpg.

Comment: @LotPings - I have tried this, it picks up the file when I press Tab, but after pressing enter I get the following: Could Not Find .jpg.

Comment: @Rik - You solution of trying \\?\D:\public_html\images\T\.jpg. worked.
Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

#### The file name is called .jpg. and I cant seem to find a way to delete it.

You can take advantage of [wildcards](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) and use the following command to delete the file:

```
del /q *
```

Example:

```
> dir
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test\test

06/01/2017  17:13    <DIR>          .
06/01/2017  17:13    <DIR>          ..
06/01/2017  17:13                 0 .jpg.
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  1,719,175,856,128 bytes free

> del /q *

> dir
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test\test

06/01/2017  17:14    <DIR>          .
06/01/2017  17:14    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  1,719,175,856,128 bytes free
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [del](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) - Delete one or more files.
- [wildcards](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html)

Comment: Sorry, that didn't resolve it for me ...

After typing del /q * - I got the following error:

D:\p\images\T\.jpg.
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @Shafiq Who owns the file? Can you edit the question to provide this information? (in explorer, right click the file > properties > security, and right click the file > properties > details)

Comment: When I try to view the security properties of the file within Explorer I get the following "The requested security information is either unavailable or can't be displayed"

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Rik - Drop into command line mode (with admin privileges) and use the following command:

```
del \\?\D:\public_html\images\T\.jpg.
```